# Java: Editable JCombobox in JOptionPane inputDialog?

Tags: java, swing

Following the example here http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JOptionPaneshowInputDialogComponentpObjectmStringtintmIconiObjectoObjecti.htm

is it possible to somehow make the default jcombobox editable? There doesn't seem to be any instantiation of JCombobox in the JOptionPane, is it possible to extend and override the default JCombobox used by JOptionPane?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with `showMessageDialog()`, by creating a `JComboBox` and transforming to editable with `setEditable()`.

Example:

```
String[] list = {"A", "B", "C"};
JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(list);
jcb.setEditable(true);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, jcb, "select or type a value", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

You can retrieve the value in the `JComboBox` with:

```
jcb.getSelectedItem()
```

Comment: What if I want to put numbers in `list= {1,2,3,4}` does this works?