# Java Swing Popup Font Selection

Tags: java, swing, fonts, combobox, popup

I want to design a action listener that will create a popup window that will have a combo box containing all the system fonts. To be more specific, I want to design a font selection option like a text editor using Java swing.

How can I do that?

Comment: [Java: Editable JCombobox in JOptionPane inputDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522854/4857909), [To get all available fonts in your system](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Togetallavailablefontsinyoursystem.htm), [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). I hope these 3 links will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example based on the three links I posted (that's why this answer is a community wiki, so I can't gain reputation from it):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });

    }

    public Example() {

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] array = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>(array);
        box.setEditable(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, box, "...", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                System.out.println(box.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get a list of system fonts available. Put that list to JComboBox and add listeners to that JComboBox.

Get system fonts with this code

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts();
```

To show the JComboBox for the user with the pop-up use JOptionPane. See tutorial for this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input

Comment: and what is the procedure of popping up?

Answer (score 0):

Or have a look at my library: https://github.com/dheid/fontchooser

You can include as a Maven dependency. It's very lightweight.